# .Net Core MVC how to find the path chosen by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have four views with four actions belong to a controller.

First view contains 3 buttons: `Button11`, `button12`, `button13`. Each button sends the ids (11 or 12 or 13) to the next action (Second view)

Second view contains 3 buttons: `Button21`, `button22`, `button23`. Each button sends the ids (21 or 22 or 23) to the next action (Third view)

Third view contains 3 buttons: `Button31`, `button32`, `button33`. Each button sends the ids (31 or 32 or 33) to the next action (Fourth view)

Fourth view show the path: Like 11, 23, 32

How to realize that?

Comment: Share your code with relevant explanation with your expectations other than this might be closed, because your questions doesn’t meet [`stackoverflow.com` guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you could add parameters to the url like s1=11&s2=23&s3=32